# Connecting two java project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two java project's and I want to connect these two Java project's in eclipse. I want a new project which will contain both two project's. I am new to Java, how I can do that. Please help me out.

Comment: Include them in build path .

Comment: Create new project and add both projects as modules in that. use maven if you like

Answer (score 3):

This will make your Eclipse project able to use other projects.

1. Right click on your project
2. Choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path.
3. Under the "Projects"-tab add your other projects.